# Importing matrix data from CSV into a numpy array, Issue with slicing the result

Tags: python, csv, numpy, slice

I have multiple CSV file to read in numpy arrays and need to use an efficient method. Currently I can correctly read the data but the result is not flexible and cant perform slicing on the output.

```
import numpy
from array import array
inputfile = "C:/temp.csv")
mx=numpy.genfromtxt(inputfile ,  names=True, dtype=int, delimiter=',')
```

with the above code I can input the data and my result looks like below:

```
array([(1, 84, 79, 11, 35, 24, 22, 40), (2, 74, 34, 94, 33, 32, 27, 79),
   (3, 19, 57, 59, 54, 86, 44, 56), (4, 67, 57, 35, 41, 46, 39, 20),
   (5, 62, 20, 65, 38, 85, 83, 64), (6, 68, 65, 71, 35, 41, 56, 85),
   (7, 61, 75, 91, 48, 55, 31, 82)], 
  dtype=[('Zone', '<i4'), ('1', '<i4'), ('2', '<i4'), ('3', '<i4'), ('4', '<i4'), ('5', '<i4'), ('6', '<i4'), ('7', '<i4')])
```

Now I want to perform a number of slicing which I cant. Can some one please help me to slice a selected column from the

Comment: Doesn't `mx['2']` work?  Just use a name from the `dtype`. or `mx[['2','4']]` for a couple of columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have there is a [structured array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html). To access the individual 'columns' you can use their field names (e.g. `mx['Zone']` to access the first 'column').

You can convert it to a 2D standard array using the [`.view()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.view.html) method:

```
mx_2d = mx.view('<i4').reshape(mx.shape[0], -1)
```

Now you can use normal slice indexing in the column dimension:

```
print(mx_2d[:, :2])
# [[ 1 84]
#  [ 2 74]
#  [ 3 19]
#  [ 4 67]
#  [ 5 62]
#  [ 6 68]
#  [ 7 61]]
```

Comment: Thanks ali_m. Your comment was very helpful and resolve my issue.